# map keys in one python dictionary to the exact value of other dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
mydict={'f1':'stream','f2':'status','f3':'remarks'}

mydict1={'stream':'RHEL','status':'pass','remarks':'none'}
```

required output

```
result={'f1':'RHEL','f2':'pass','f3': 'none'}
```

---

```
def function(mydict, mydict1):
    for key,value in mydict1.iteritems():
        print mydict1[key]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> mydict = {'f1': 'stream', 'f2': 'status', 'f3': 'remarks'}
>>> mydict1 = {'stream': 'RHEL', 'status': 'pass', 'remarks': 'none'}
>>> {key: mydict1[value] for key, value in mydict.items()}
{'f1': 'RHEL', 'f2': 'pass', 'f3': 'none'}
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, iterate through `mydict.items()` instead, and then append to `result` dictionary, this way:

```
>>> mydict={'f1':'stream','f2':'status','f3':'remarks'}
>>> mydict1={'stream':'RHEL','status':'pass','remarks':'none'}    
>>>def function(mydict, mydict1):
           for key,value in mydict.items():
               result[key] = mydict1[value]
           return result
>>>function(mydict, mydict1)
{'f1': 'RHEL', 'f2': 'pass', 'f3': 'none'}
```

Of course, this could be lot simplified as [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) posted in his answer, using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).